# CSS changes not rendering in production rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, media-queries, passenger, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to add media query changes to a rails site built with foundation. The server is apache and phusion. However when I make changes to the stylesheet nothing changes on the site.

After I save the changes I'm also doing

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

in termial and still nothing changes. I imagine it has something to do with rails production. Any way to overwrite this?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check to make sure that your browser hasn't cached everything.  So either empty the cache or try a different browser.

If that doesn't work, try running `rake assets:clean` before each push (whenever you've precompiled locally).